# How to restart containers which image changed?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use `docker-compose` to start a set of unrelated docker containers. I use `docker-compose` for that because of the ease of configuration via `docker-compose.yaml` and the centralized configuration this file brings.

**One problem I have is the update of images, or actually of containers after an image update.** I update them via `docker-compose pull` but the containers previously spawned do not restart by themselves. I have two possible solutions, both doable but none ideal:

- restart all the containers after a `pull`. This would introduce unavailability which is not a critical thing in my home environment but still (especially Home Assistant restarting is a pain as the lights are reset)
- write some code to check which images IDs have changed during the pull and restart the relevant containers (removing them first). This is the solution I will be using if there is nothing better.

I was wondering if there was a better soution.

This is a home environment so I would like to avoid heavy duty solutions such as Kubernetes.

Swarm mode could work but I just read about it and it looks more like a solution to ensure  state more than a containers manager (in the sense that it would restart containers based on the freshness of the image they were spawned from).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you `docker pull image`, `docker-compose -f "docker-compose.yml" up -d` will *only* restart the containers for which there is a new version of the image after the `docker pull`. It will not impact the containers whose image stays the same. This setup works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate -d
```

> if there are existing containers for a service, and the service’s
>   configuration or image was changed after the container’s creation,
>   docker-compose up picks up the changes by stopping and recreating the
>   containers (preserving mounted volumes). To prevent Compose from
>   picking up changes, use the **--no-recreate** flag.
>
> If you want to force Compose to stop and recreate all containers, use
>   the **--force-recreate** flag.

[docker-compose up -CLI](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/)

***NOTE:Recreate containers even if their configuration and image haven't changed.***